# Linux/Ubuntu create executable command for sh file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to create executable command for Ubuntu.

I have `/dir/bin/start.sh`

I can execute it this way

```
./dir/bin/start.sh
```

But I was wondering how to put it to Ubuntu configuration or something, so it will
be possible to invoke it from shell with just

```
start
```

Comment: `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/dir/of/start.sh`, `cd /path/to/dir/of/start.sh`, `ln -s start.sh start`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Or: `alias start=/dir/bin/start.sh`. Or `start() { /dir/bin/start.sh "$@" ; }`

Comment: Lots of way to skin that cat `:p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by either:

- Add the directory of the command to the `$PATH` variable, thus:

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/dir/bin
  ```

  To do this persistent, you must add this line to the `~/.profile` file:

  ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/dir/bin' >> ~/.profile
  ```
- Create a shortcut (for instance with `ln -s '/dir/bin/start.sh' start`) in a directory that is added to the path;

  ```
  cd <pathdirectory>
  ln -s '/dir/bin/start.sh' start
  ```
- Create an alias so that the shell simply replaces the command:

  ```
  echo 'alias start=./dir/bin/start.sh' >> ~/.profile
  ```

---

How/Why does this work

If you type a command in the shell, it will first look for aliases, and replace the aliases. So if you have defined an alias for `start`, it will simply replace is by `./dir/bin/start.sh`; so as if you have written it yourself.

Next the shell will try to find the interpretation of the command. If the command is a file (for instance by using a alias), the file is executed. Otherwise, the system falls back on `$PATH`s.

`$PATH`s is a sequence of paths where the system searches for a file with that name. It searches the paths in that order and searches through all the files for a file with the same name. If such file exists, it runs that file.

You can thus do a few things:

- Place such program in the directory; but that's not really a nice option, because different projects are then grouped together;
- Use a shortcut (the `ln` solution), in that case you only add a "representative" in the path folder;
- Extend the number of paths by performing the `PATH=$PATH:/dir/bin`, so that it will search your project as well.